# Python: automatize JSON request loading

Tags: python

I'm parsing a JSON request which has many cameras and I need to somehow load all the variables from the cameras and pass them to web server (HTML, JS). For now, I have about 20 camera devices and I do load all the cameras once, you can see. Is there any way to automatize it? I need to pass variables to HTML like - camera2_title, camera3_title......

If I would use - `for x in range(total_cameras)` and use variables like camera_title that would just overwrite and how can I return these variables to HTML?

JSON format that I'm loading

```
{
        "status": "ok",
        "total_cameras": 3,
        "cameras": [
            {
                "camera_id": 3,
                "camera_name": "hikvision 1",
                "camera_ip": "73.2.51.0",
                "camera_lat": 53.736406,
                "camera_log": 15.11621,
                "camera_street": "slezeviciaus g. 7",
                "camera_lastUPD": "10 jan 16:04 2020"
            },
            {
                "camera_id": 4,
                "camera_name": "hikvision 2",
                "camera_ip": "213.2.51.0",
                "camera_lat": 51.67,
                "camera_log": -5.06,
                "camera_street": "Stanevy 4",
                "camera_lastUPD": "10 Jan 2020 07:17:37"
            },
            {
                "camera_id": 5,
                "camera_name": "hikvision 3",
                "camera_ip": "45.89.25.1",
                "camera_lat": -42.683,
                "camera_log": 41.856,
                "camera_street": "Kudirkos st",
                "camera_lastUPD": "10 jan 16:04 2020"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Python code:

```
@app.route('/<api_key>')
def main_screen2(api_key=None):
    try:
        api_key = api_key or 'None'
        Reach_sr = Back_End()
        xx = Reach_sr.GetCameras_Info(api_key)
        Extra = False
        Loaded_Cameras = 0
        JSON_DATA = json.loads(xx)
        try:
            Camera_name_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_name"]
            Camera_Lat_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_lat"]
            Camera_Log_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_log"]
            Camera_Street_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_street"]
            Camera_IP_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_ip"]
            Camera_ID_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_id"]
            Camera_LASTUPDATED_1 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][0]["camera_lastUPD"]

            Loaded_Cameras += 1
        except Exception as er:
            # Log error & make a return
            #log.error("Camera 20 failed to load it's info... ERROR: {er}")
            return "S"
        try:
            Camera_name_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_name"]
            Camera_Lat_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_lat"]
            Camera_Log_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_log"]
            Camera_Street_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_street"]
            Camera_IP_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_ip"]
            Camera_ID_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_id"]
            Camera_LASTUPDATED_2 = JSON_DATA["cameras"][1]["camera_lastUPD"]

            Loaded_Cameras += 1
        except Exception as er:
            # Log error & make a return
            #log.error("Camera 20 failed to load it's info... ERROR: {er}")
            return "test"

        return render_template('MAIN_index.html', camera2_title=camera2_title, camera2_lat=camera2_lat, camera2_log=camera2_log )
```

Comment: Why you just do not pass cameras = JSON_DATA['cameras'] to your HTML template and in template  {% for camera in cameras %} {{ camera.camera_name }} ( I'm not sure about template engine you use but it supposes to have a looping through the object), but the way is for your question is a dictionary render_template('MAIN_index.html', **{ f"camera{camera[id]}_title": camera['camera_name'] for camera in JSON_DATA["cameras"] })

Comment: I'm really green on HTML and JS, where do I need to put {% for camera in cameras %} {{ camera.camera_name }}  ?  Should I create any function or what

Comment: {% for camera in cameras %}
    <div class="flash">{{ camera.camera_name }}</div>
 {% endfor %} [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: How can I access let's say camera2 name right now in HTML? with this - `{% for camera in cameras %} <div class="flash">{{ camera.camera_name }}</div> {% endfor %}`

Comment: {{ cameras[1].camera_name }}

Comment: I did this inside a <head>{% for camera in cameras %}
      <div class="flash">{{ camera.camera_name }}</div> 
    {% endfor %}</head> but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206015/discussion-between-ivi-and-dzitc).

Answer (score 0):

Caution: all written bellow is written in a context, that reader knows about good practice to verify input data structure before using it dynamic way. ( https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous is one of the many good checkers)

When you are sure in correct structure of your dict you can use unpacking to pass a dict as key value args.

Also it's a good idea to use cycles/lists in your jinja2 template to generate a page for multiple cameras. So render_template should take something like lst_camera_titles instead of camera_(1 .. n)_title. Without any binding to its' count.

So you can do something like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# Dict how calls dict[key] = list() if you trying to access non-existing key.
template_render_params = defaultdict(list)


for camera in JSON_DATA["cameras"]:
   template_render_params['camera_names'].append(camera['camera_name'])
   ...
   # etc for all args or if you've got too many args, you can rewrite it a function,
   # who takes dict {input_json_key: template_render_argument_name}
   # and returns a dict with key-value arguments for render_template

return render_template('MAIN_index.html', **template_render_params)
```

Comment: How can I access the variable in HTML? - {{ camera_name }} ?

Comment: @DzITC  yes, it passes your dict as it was key value args .
You can read about it in 5 minutes here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/ (part two is your case).

Comment: Uhh, still can't understand how to access the - camera1_name for ex. in html.

Comment: maybe my code need some explanations: defaultdict - is a dict, that calls passed constructor, when hasn't such key ( in our case you can think about it as a dict with all possible keys defined as empty list), so you pass 'camera_name' as list it's correct to call it 'camera_names'. Also Camera_name - begins with uppercase, so {{ Camera_name }} but more canonical is to rename it to lowercase. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: But it does pass all variables as Camera_name  how do I know which camera is it?

Comment: It's a list and it's ordered, so camera_names - stores all names sequentially. So camera_names[0] - is a name of first camera, it's ip is camera_ips[0].
Do you need to work with params or with cameras ? ( you mostly need some kind of data about all cameras (ex. list ip's of all cameras), or all data about cameras one by one? ( ex. you want a list drop-down menus with camera info.)
In second case your need list of dicts instead of dict of lists.

Comment: 'camera_names' is undefined

Comment: Is corresponding dict key named exactly "camera_name"? (not "Camera_name")